# SQL Multi Order by Count with Criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query standings from MotoGP Race result

my sql is

```
SELECT `Rider`, `Team`, `Bike`,SUM(`Points`)
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE `Year` = 2015 AND `Classes` = "MotoGP"
GROUP BY `Year`,`Rider`
HAVING SUM(`Points`)
ORDER BY SUM(`Points`) DESC
```

If 2 or more riders have same SUM('Points'), the next order is by number of 1st race position.
I put the race position on 'Pos' field.

Pos value: 1,2,3,4,5 ...

Please help for the 2nd order. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the `HAVING` clause:

```
ORDER BY SUM(`Points`) DESC,
         SUM(RacePosition = 1) DESC
```

For multiple positions, I think you need to add the condition for each one:

```
ORDER BY SUM(`Points`) DESC,
         SUM(RacePosition = 1) DESC,
         SUM(RacePosition = 2) DESC,
         SUM(RacePosition = 3) DESC
```

At some point, perhaps `SUM(RacePosition)` would do what you want.

Comment: i think not SUM, i need count of  pos = 1 DESC

Comment: @vincmeister  . . . That is what `sum(pos  = 1)` does.  But if you really want, you could be verbose an write `sum(case when pos = 1 then 1 else 0 end)`.

Comment: hello Gordon, please help little more. What if the order by 1st position if 2 or more riders have same 1st position wins, then order by number of 2nd pos, then by 3rd. thanks